# How to add a condition in my IF CONTROLLER using jmeter and groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am using jmeter 3.3 and groovy and have a IF CONDITION which filters according to the response code.

here is what I am doing and it works:

```
${__jexl3(${code} != 000)}
```

Now I want to add an AND logic to this condition or an OR logic

for instance doing this:

```
${__jexl3(${code} != 000)} && ${__jexl3(${code} != 901)}
```

but this does not seem to work.

what is the proper way of adding logic operator?

Comment: Did you try this ${__jexl3(${code} != 000 && ${code} != 000)}

Comment: it works if u respond I will accept it

Comment: Kiril S. posted the answer below, you can accept it.

Comment: u were the first but fine

Comment: thanks for accepting. I wrote the answer before comment came, but was testing it which took a few mins ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your change the statement to

```
${__jexl3(${code} != 000 && ${code} != 000)}
```

it will work (i.e. you pull both conditions under the same *jexl3* evaluation).

The thing is, you don't need jexl3 evaluation at all. Your *If Controller* will use JavaScriptby default, and thus can be configured like this:

[image]

So your code can be

```
${code} != 000 && ${code} != 000
```

(of course it doesn't make much sense to put same condition there, but I assume it's an example)

Comment: Advising to use Javascript, while it works, is not ideal. As the jmeter5 UI indicates now, for performance it's best to use groovy or jexl3.

Comment: @JonL. This is a 3-year old answer. I didn't deal with Jmeter for a long time, but back in the day you had to install groovy separately. So doing that for a sake of a small performance benefit of a simple comparison is not ideal either (it's called a premature optimization).

Answer (score 6):

- If you want [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) you need to use a single function call rather than 2 separate:

  ```
  ${__jexl3("${code}" != "000" && "${code}" != "901" ,)}
  ```
- If you want to use [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) - refer the variable as `vars.get('code')` like:

  ```
  ${__groovy((!vars.get('code').equals('000') && !vars.get('code').equals('901')),)}
  ```

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)